# how do I access jquery functions form inside colorbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am trying to submit a form via ajax from inside a colorbox, but when I submit the form is tells me that the function is not available. Need help to understand

/* Inside colorbox */

```
<div id="messageform" style="display:none;">

<?php echo Form::open(); ?>

<?php echo Form::label('message', 'message'); ?> <br />
<?php echo Form::textarea('message', NULL,array('id'=>'messagecontent')); ?> <br />

<button id="sendmessage" onclick="sendmessage('<?= Auth::instance()->get_user(); ?>', '<?= $user->id; ?>', 'test message');">Send</button>

<?php echo Form::close(); ?>

</div>
```

/* AJAX function located before body close*/

```
function sendmessage(user_id, to_id, message)
{
var loadUrl= '<?=url::base()?>message/send';

$.post(loadUrl,{uid: user_id, tid: to_id, message: message}, function(code){}); 
}
```

I am getting a 'sendmessage' not found from the console

/* open colorbox */

The colorbox is being launched via link click

```
$('.openmessagelink').click(function(){

$.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", open:true, href:"#messageform",
            onClosed: function() {
                 $('#messageform').hide();
            },
            onOpen: function() {
                 $('#messageform').show();
            }
           }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function has the same name as the butrón id.

Comment: Thank you soo much that was completely right
I am still learning , maybe you can also help me

I am trying to pass the textarea value into that function but can't figure it out, this is what I am trying
<script>var message = $("textarea#messagecontent").val();</script>
    
<button onclick="sendmessage('<?= Auth::instance()->get_user(); ?>', '<?= $user->id; ?>', message);">Send</button>

Comment: Just remove the textarea before #messagecontent